# Map stringified regexp to RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to do following:

```
var regex = /^\/(.*)\/?$/i;

// "/^\/(.*)\/?$/i"
var stringifiedRegex = regex.string();

// //^\/(.*)\/?$/i/
var newRegex = new RegExp(stringifiedRegex);
```

As you see when converting the stringified regex back to a real RegExp the regex is modified and does not match anymore the original one.

Any idea how to fix this?

Bodo

Comment: `var newRegex = eval(stringifiedRegex);` But why?

Comment: @NagaJolokia Don't use `eval` if it's not needed. There are two ways to achieve the desired effect without using `eval` at all.

Comment: Indeed. That's why I want to know what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: why did u you turn the regex to String?

Comment: @NagaJolokia Pretty obvious: He wants to create a new instance of the RegExp with the same source and flags. A legitimate use case is that `.exec` modifies the state of the regular expression (which can be reset though, by setting `lastIndex`).

Comment: Did you mean `.toString()` and not `.string()`?

Comment: @RobW There's no need for strings for that. That's just silly.

Comment: RegExp function takes the string without flags, the string needs to be stripped first, to the plain "^\/(.*)\/?$"

Comment: can somebody provide an example?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you are trying to achieve please?

Comment: Thanks. If we know the bigger picture then we might be able to suggest alternative approaches. Hint: regexps have properties such as `source` and `global`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *have* to store the regex as a single string (including all flags), you can use a regex to split the regex into the parts you need to pass to `new RegExp` (well, that was a sentence...):

```
> regex = /^\/(.*)\/?$/i;
/^\/(.*)\/?$/i
> str = regex.toString()
"/^\/(.*)\/?$/i"
> m = str.match(/^[/](.*)[/]([^/]*)$/)
["/^\/(.*)\/?$/i", "^\/(.*)\/?$", "i"]
> newRegex = new RegExp(m[1], m[2])
/^\/(.*)\/?$/i
```

The regex matches `/`, then captures as much as possible, then matches the closing `/` and captures possible flags.

Alternatively, if you can store it across multiple fields in your database, store the source string and three booleans for the three flags separately:

```
> regex = /^\/(.*)\/?$/i;
/^\/(.*)\/?$/i
> regex.source
"^\/(.*)\/?$"
> regex.global
false
> regex.ignoreCase
true
> regex.multiline
false
```

Comment: There's no need to parse the results of regex.toString(). It's already been parsed for you.

Comment: @NagaJolokia I was already editing. but the OP might be restricted to storing the entire regex (including flags) as a single string

Comment: Good point. Some more info. on the problem from the OP would help.